# What is the reasoning behind why the ratio test works?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, intuition

The ratio test says that, if we have the positive series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n,$$

such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L$, then

**(1)** if $L < 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is absolutely convergent;

**(2)** if $L > 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is divergent;

**(3)** if $L = 1$, then the ratio test gives no information.

I want to understand the reasons behind **why** and **how** this works, rather than just memorising formulae.

I have attempted to reason about this theorem myself. It can be seen that we're taking the ratio between the second term in the series, $a_{n+1}$, and the first term in the series, $a_n$. This is exactly how one finds the common ratio in a geometric sequence ($r = \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} )$. We then take the limit of this ratio, which I assume is to find the relative rate of change between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$. In which case, it is more effective to take the absolute value of the limit, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \begin{vmatrix}{ \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} }\end{vmatrix} = L$. This seems analagous to how the **limit comparison test** theorem works. Therefore, I presume that, if $L < 1$, then this implies that $a_n$ has a greater rate of change than $a_{n+1}$, which implies that each successive term in the series is getting smaller, and so as we go to infinity, each successive term is converging towards $0$. As such, the series should converge to some value. Analogously, I presume that, if $L > 1$, then this implies that $a_{n+1}$ has a greater rate of change than $a_n$, which implies that each successive term in the series is getting larger, and so as we go to infinity, the terms diverge towards infinity.

Is this reasoning correct? If anything is incorrect, then please clarify *why* it is incorrect, and *what* the correct reasoning is.

Comment: "each succesive term is converging towards zero.  As such, the series should converge."  This is a famously fallacious statement.  The harmonic series tends termwise to zero, but the series diverges.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I forgot about that. You're absolutely correct. In which case, what is the correct way to reason about that section?

Comment: @GCab Which is **not** less than $1$ . . .

Comment: @GCab  That's correct, the ratio test doesn't apply to the harmonic series.  But the statement I quoted is still invalid.

Comment: next time read wikipedia's entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Proof

Comment: @user1952009 The proof on that page is not justified. For instance, it says 'Then r is strictly between L and 1 ...'. Why is $r$ strictly between $L$ and $1$? This does not help in developing an understanding of the concepts.

Comment: The first line should be "The ratio test says that, if we have the positive series"

Comment: @zhw. Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 9):

You have some ideas correct, but remember that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ does not imply that $\sum a_n$ converges. So we need something more than that. However, for the case when $L>1$, your reasoning is correct.

For the case $L<1$, we know that there exists some $r < 1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq r < 1,$$
whenever $n \geq N$.

Therefore,

$$
a_{N+1} \leq ra_N,
$$
$$
a_{N+2} \leq ra_{N+1}  \leq r^2a_N
$$
$$
a_{N+3} \leq ra_{N+2}  \leq r^3a_N,
$$
and in general
$$
a_{N+n} \leq r^na_N.
$$

Therefore, at least eventually, we can compare the series from above with a convergent geometric series $\sum a_N r^n$, which implies the convergence of the original series $\sum a_n$.

Comment: I'm not sure if your notation has the same meaning as mine or if you've defined it differently. For instance, how can $\dfrac{ a_{n+1} }{a_n} < r$? I've defined $r = \dfrac{ a_{n+1} }{a_n}$.

Comment: My notation is different. If you set $r$ equal to the ratio, then it is changing with $n$. But when $L < 1$, such a fixed $r$ exists as I employed it in my answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what $r$ and $N$ are?

Comment: Since $lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L < 1$, take $\epsilon = \frac{1-L}{2}$, then by the definition of the limit, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Longrightarrow -\epsilon <  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - L < \epsilon$, so you can take for example $r = \epsilon + L = \frac{1+L}{2}$

Comment: I'm sorry but this still doesn't tell me what $N$ and $r$ are supposed to be. I cannot see the relevance between your answer and my original question.

Comment: Then you do not understand the meaning of limits.

Comment: Looking at this answer years later, I stand by my initial thoughts: The answer is written poorly, in that (1) it does not provide justification/explanation for its claims, and (2) it does not make clear how it is answering my question. The goal of an explanation is not to explain it to yourself, nor to explain it to others that already understand the concept, but to explain it to those who *do not*, so that they may learn.

Comment: I strongly disagree. (1) It justifies its claims: there's an implicit appeal to the definition of limits [which was painfully expanded in the comments], an induction, and a reference to a geometric series and the comparison test. (2) This is quite a vague criticism. It proves your "1)", so is obviously relevant. In my view the problem lies with you and not the answer; remember, you asked for "why and how", not a rigorous proof. I've seen this situation come up with my students, and the solution is always to just talk it over one-on-one and fill in that student's particular gaps in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an intuitive explanation.

A geometric series has constant ratio between consecutive terms. Hence when we take the ratio $r(n)=a_{n+1}/a_n$ for an arbitrary series $\sum_k a_k,$ we are measuring how far it is similar to or different from a geometrical series.

However, this is not enough to determine the nature of the convergence or otherwise of such a series. What we need is the *eventual behaviour* of this series. Thus the important point is that if the ratio is constant at infinity, then the series may be called asymptotically geometric.

Hence, if the limit of the ratio $r(n)$ is less than $1$ in magnitude, the series converges. If it is greater than $1$ in magnitude, it does not converge. If the ratio at infinity is either $\pm 1,$ then this test is indecisive.

Comment: Your first paragraph is interesting as an intuitive explanation. The problem I see is that your last paragraph doesn't follow from the first: The ratio $r(n)=a_{n+1}/a_n$ measures how far it is similar to or different from a geometrical series, but I don't see how this leads to the intuitive conclusion that "if the limit of the ratio $r(n)$ is less than $1$ in magnitude, the series converges; if it is greater than $1$ in magnitude, it does not converge; if the ratio at infinity is either $\pm 1,$ then this test is indecisive." In fact, following this intuition, wouldn't it make sense to [...]

Comment: [...] say that $L = 1$ means that the geometric series converges, since, based on this intuition, this would mean that the geometric series has constant ratio between consecutive terms?

Comment: @ThePointer You are missing the point that a geometrical series converges if and only if $|r(n)|<1.$ Hence if your arbitrary series has $|r(n)|<1$ for $n=\infty,$ then it converges.

Answer (score 0):

$L<1$ means that the ratio $r=\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$ is eventually less than the positive ratio of a converging geometric series, i.e, less than $1$. Analogously for $L > 1$.

Note that the condition that the principal term $a_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ is sufficient for a series to be convergent, but it is not a necessary condition.

Comment: Your answer is just making claims without *explanation*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at each of the three cases $L > 1$, $L = 1$, and $L < 1$ in detail.

- *Case 1:* Assume $L > 1$. Then there exists some $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$, we have $a_{n+1}/a_n > (L+1)/2 > 1.$ Therefore, for all $n \geq N$,

$$a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}...\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}a_N \geq \left( \frac{L+1}{2} \right)^{n-N} a_N \geq a_N > 0,$$

so the sequence $a_n$ fails the [$n$th term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test): $a_n$ is bounded below by a positive number, and so the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ cannot converge. (In fact, $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ when $L > 1$.)

- *Case 2:* It is possible to find both convergent and divergent series for which $L = 1$.

When $a_n = 1/n^2$, $L = 1$, and the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \text{ converges to } \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

When $a_n = 1/n$, $L = 1$, but the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \text{ diverges.}$$

- *Case 3:* Assume $L < 1$. Then there exists some $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$, we have $a_{n+1}/a_n < (L+1)/2 < 1.$ Therefore, for all $n \geq N$,

$$a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}...\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}a_N \leq \left( \frac{L+1}{2} \right)^{n-N} a_N,$$

and we can show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is bounded [by the comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test): $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n + \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n + \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_N \left( \frac{L+1}{2} \right)^{n-N};$$

but $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n$ is finite, and $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_N \left( \frac{L+1}{2} \right)^{n-N} = a_N \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left( \frac{L+1}{2} \right)^j$$ is a convergent geometric series (since $(L+1)/2 < 1$). QED.

Answer (score 0):

I really though that user333870's answer covered it. But I guess I can give a short intuitive meaning.

If you apply the ratio test and discover that $L<1$, then this means that the terms of the series grow more slowly than a converging geometric series. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem that means that the series converges.

Dually if $L>1$, then this means that the terms of the series grow more quickly than the terms of a divergent geometric series, and thus diverges as well.