# Please verify my proof of the ratio test and my reasoning about it. (I want to post it as an answer to another question).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I recently asked the question [What is the reasoning behind why the ratio test works?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008784/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-why-the-ratio-test-works/2008792?noredirect=1#comment4124634_2008792) Although the answer of a user has been up-voted, as a college student who is just learning the concept, I did not initially find it illuminating at all. In the interest of posting an answer that is understandable to people such as myself, I sought to formulate a more detailed answer. I would appreciate it if you, the good people of MSE, could review my elaborated reasoning about the proof, to verify that it is correct to post as an answer.

I would also like to thank the user dxiv for their help in the question [Help with reasoning about a component of the wikipedia proof for the ratio test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010075/help-with-reasoning-about-a-component-of-the-wikipedia-proof-for-the-ratio-test).

The proof is as follows.

The hypothesis is that if $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}\begin{vmatrix}{ \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} }\end{vmatrix} < 1$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely.

One way to prove that a series converges is by bounding its value.  The series is already bounded from below, since $L \ge 0$. This is because we are taking the absolute value of $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Therefore, we can show that the series converges absolutely by showing that its terms will eventually become less than those of some (any) convergent geometric series.

Let $r$ be the common ratio of some convergent geometric series.

As a random example, let $r = \dfrac{L + 1}{2}$, where $0 \le L \lt 1$. Here, $\dfrac{L + 1}{2}$ is defined as being the mid-point between $L$ and $1$.

$r$ is claimed to be strictly between $L$ and $1$.

We can verify this:

$r = \dfrac{L + 1}{2}$

$\Rightarrow 2r - 1 = L$

$\therefore 1 > 2r - 1 = L \ge 0$

$ \Rightarrow 2 > 2r = L + 1 \ge 1$

$\Rightarrow 1 > r = \dfrac{L + 1}{2} \ge \dfrac{1}{2}$

$\therefore 1 > r = \dfrac{L + 1}{2} \ge L \ge 0$, since $0 \le L \lt 1$.

As stated in the hypothesis, we know that $|a_{n+1}|$ is defined to be the next term in the series. $|a_n|$ is defined to be the current term of the series.

As previously stated, we have already bounded the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ from below. We must now bound it from above.

What does it mean for the series to be bounded from above? It means that $|a_{n+1}|$ (the next term in the series) cannot exceed $|a_n|$ (the current term in the series).

We also defined $r$, where $1 > r \ge L \ge 0$, to be the common ratio of a convergent geometric series. This makes sense, since we know that if $|r| < 1$, the geometric series is convergent.

Therefore, we are saying:

$|a_{n+1}| < r^n|a_n|$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+1}| < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n|a_n|$

$|r| < 1$

$\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+1}| < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n|a_n|$, where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n|a_n|$ is convergent.

As have proven, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+1}|$ is bounded from above and must therefore also be convergent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use
$$
2=1+1>1+L>L+L=2L
$$
to find $1>r=\frac{1+L}2>L$.

You get $\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<r$ not for all $L$, but only for almost all, i.e., excluding finitely many, i.e., for all $n>N$ for some $N$.

Then the recursion only tells you $|a_{N+k}|<r^k·|a_N|$.

Now your upper bound for the series of absolutes is a sum of a finite sum and a geometric series,
$$
\sum_n|a_n|\le\sum_{n<N}|a_n|+\sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_N|·r^k=\sum_{n<N}|a_n|+|a_N|·\frac1{1-r}
$$

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Please clarify.

Comment: As it is, your proof is wrong. The first point is to shorten the first half of your contemplations. The second says that limits are something that happens at (index) infinity, for finite values the sequence might be badly behaved. Then your solution of the recursion $|a_{n+1}|<r·|a_n|$ for $n\ge N$ is completely wrong, as is your use of it in the construction of the majorant.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. But I am still unsure where the finite value series come from?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^∞ |a_{N+k}|<\sum_{k=0}^∞ r^k⋅|a_N|$ from $|a_{N+2}|<r·|a_{N+1}|<r·r·|a_N|$, $|a_{N+3}|<r·|a_{N+2}|<r·r^2·|a_N|$ etc.

Comment: @ThePointer: But yesterday in the comments to the previous posts, you already reproduced all this correctly. Why the step-back in this question? Sloppy typing?

Comment: My latest comment to yesterday's post was exactly what I posted in the original post. Note that the comment didn't use finite series or $N$. The latest comment reasoned about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+i}| < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^i|a_n|$, which is what I've done/posted above. I assumed that this was correct, since it was left with an up-vote (in yesterday's post). Unfortunately, it must have been incorrect. I'm now working to reason about your comments so that I can post improvements. :)

Comment: Your post says $L < r < 1$ but shouldn't it be $ L /le r < 1 $? Also, you said $L < r$ not for all $ L$. However, you also claimed $L < r < 1$. Therefore, we must have $L < r$ for all $L$?

Comment: There is only one $L$, if at all, for each series under consideration. -- Please read again carefully the formulas in your question with emphasis on the indices used and compare them to your previous efforts.